# Removing file from Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I have **added** a file to google docs, which is not as similar to making a copy. It is like making a *shortcut like thing* (in windows terminology) or *link like thing* (in linux terminolgy) with a catch that if you remove any of the file the parent or the child both of them gets deleted.

My question is how to delete any one of them?

Searching something like this "removing added google docs" gives a completely irrelevant result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

At this time it's not possible.

## Explanation

I think that instead of seeing the Google Documents and the other Google editors apps like an OS file explorer we should see them as Google Search, so instead of asking how to "delete" we should ask something like

> "how to remove"

as the question of this title does at this time, or

> how to avoid that a file is shown in the "search results"

So I imagine that the solution will be something similar to [Google Custom Search](https://cse.google.com/cse/) or add-on that removes certain "search results", like [Personal Block List (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef?hl=es)